# How to create a vertically asymmetrical grid in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, css, photo-editing, website-templates

I'm working on a site. The width will be fixed, but the length will vary.

What would be the best way to create a grid like the following in Photoshop?:

[image: here is the image of the grid, please someone tell me how to make similar in photoshop based on the previous details]

Comment: Edited the question as required by Ahmed - Please re-vote if you feel it is now a better fit. Brendan's answer was good, so I thought it'd be a shame to lose it. Ahmed, if Brendan's solution was good, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is create a few layers and give them layer masks that are sized to the different image sizes that you want. I did this by using the `Rectangular Marquee` tool to make a selection, then going to `Select` > `Transform Selection` and sizing the selection to be 150px wide by 50, 100, 150, and 200px high:

[image]

Now, drag your images in and apply the masks to the images by holding <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> while clicking a layer mask in your `Layers` palette and dragging it to your new image layer:

[image]

Then, click the little link icon that's between the image thumbnail and the mask thumbnail in the `Layers` palette. Next, click the image thumbnail to select it, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to resize the image without disturbing your layer mask:

[image]

Repeat as necessary. I would find this to be more intuitive than opening up separate images, cropping/sizing them, then pulling them in; plus, if you want to change how they're cropped later you can do that more easily here. If you convert your image to a smart object right after placing it on the canvas before applying the clipping mask, then that allows for even more flexibility.